# (Nuitka error) __main__.py: can't open file '...\gen_py\3.9'

Tags: python-3.x, nuitka

I currently have an error with Nuitka which I am starting to use.

I want to compile my script including a folder and its contents, here is the command I use:
`python -m nuitka --follow-imports --enable-plugin=tk-inter --onefile --show-progress --include-data-dir=C:\Users\user\Desktop\MyProgram\datas=datas MyScript.py`
but every time i ended up with this error:

```
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Optimizing module 'win32com', 71 more modules to go after that.
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Doing module local optimizations for 'win32com'.
__main__.py: can't open file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9'.
```

And I don't have it when I remove '--include-data-dir'
Am I ordering incorrectly or is this another problem?

Thanks!

Edit: You must delete the `%temp%/gen_py` folder, it will be re-generated and problem fixed!

Comment: Can you please share you solution as answer, so that future programmers can easily see it?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete this specified folder (gen_py) and retry, it will work

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.